# registering windowsbase assembly SqlServer CLR

Tags: .net, sql-server, devexpress, clr

I've write a CLR storedprocedure and all was ok until today when I've introduced a new dll and I'm trying to register some third party libraries to SqlServer 2008 R2 but when I run this commands:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [DevExpress.Data] FROM 'C:\MyProject\DevExpress.Data.v12.2.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
```

SqlServer throws me an error:

```
Assembly 'DevExpress.Data.v12.2' references assembly 'windowsbase, version=3.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35.', which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed (reason: 2(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)). Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.
```

No 3.0 version is present on c:\Windows\Microsoft.Net except v4.0, so when I run

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [WindowsBase] FROM 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\WindowsBase.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
```

SqlServer throws me another error:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'WindowsBase' failed because the assembly is built for an unsupported version of the Common Language Runtime.
```

It looks like there was a v3.0 of windowsbase but the only one I can find is about v4.0.

Anyone can help me!?

Thanks in advance

Marco

Answer (score 1):

Could this be of any help?

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [WindowsBase]
FROM 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll' 
WITH permission_set = unsafe 
go
```

Edit: as Matthew pointed out, might not work. Unfortunately, this works on SQL Server up to 2008 R2. On newer versions (for security/stability reasons?) some CLR assemblies are not allowed, so you have to call native DLL (which is a lot less safe/stable).

Comment: Msg 6586, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Assembly 'WindowsBase' could not be installed because existing policy would keep it from being used.

Answer (score 0):

It worked like this for me:

```
create assembly [WindowsBase]
from'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\WindowsBase.dll'
with permission_set = unsafe;
```

Comment: Just 8 year later and the same code of OP.

Comment: I needed to install EPPlus to read Excel files from a Sql-Clr procedure in Sql Server 2016. It required installing WindowsBase, and only this version, which I wrote, worked for me. This version was not in your post - Framework64.